# How to create an Elasticache with more than one node in Redis?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Elasticache was updated to support more than one node for Redis clusters. In the console more than one node can be created for the same replication group, but using boto, if the option num_cache_nodes is set to more than 1 the API throwns and error saying that it cannot create with more than one node. Is the boto library not up to date or there is another gotcha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of August 2015 you cannot, even in the console. The field is there, but you cannot set it to anything other than one.

What you can do is to create a replication group with various Redis cache clusters (each of them size one), one acting as read/write master and the rest as read replicas.

> At this time, ElastiCache supports single-node Redis clusters.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/CacheNode.Redis.html